# How do I print a letter based on the index of the string?

Tags: java

I want to print a letter instead of the index position using the indexOf(); method.
The requirement is that: Inputs a second string from the user.  Outputs the character after the first instance of the string in the phrase.  If the string is not in the phrase, outputs a statement to that effect. For example, the input is 3, upside down, d. The output should be "e", I got part of it working where it inputs an integer rather than a string of that particular position. How would I output a string?

```
                else if (option == 3){
                int first = 0;
                String letter = keyboard.next();
                first = phrase.indexOf(letter,1);
            if (first == -1){
                    System.out.print("'"+letter+"' is not in '"+phrase+"'");
            }
            else {
                    System.out.print(first + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out the [charAt](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_charat.asp) method.

Comment: He's trying to tell us something, I know it.

Comment: How would I use the charAt method in this case?

Comment: You say "I want to print a letter instead of the index position." So it sounds like you already know the index of the letter you are looking for. The `charAt` method takes that index as an input, and returns the character in the string at that index.

Answer (score 0):

## [String.charAt(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

You can access a single character, or a letter, by caling método `charAt()` from `String` class

### Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
    char firstLetter = phrase.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("First Letter : " + firstLetter);
}
```

So, running this code, assuming the input is `StackOverFlow`, the output will be `S`

In your code I think doing the follow will work:

### Your Code

```
 String letter = keyboard.next();
 first = letter.charAt(0);
```

That might help!

Comment: How would I print a character after the first instance, for example if the input is Keyboard and a, the output should be the character after it which would be "r"

Comment: So, what you want is print the first letter based on a letter the user has input?
For example, for the word Keyboard, and user inputs letter 'a' the first letter might be 'R'. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I have to combine both the indexOf(): method and the charAt(): method

Comment: Is this the hangman game? Another dubt, the phrase is a fixed value?

Comment: Yes the phrase is fixed

Answer (score 0):

### Based on those comments

> So, what you want is print the first letter based on a letter the user
>   has input? For example, for the word Keyboard, and user inputs letter
>   'a' the first letter might be 'R'. Is that it? – Guerino Rodella
>
> Yes, I have to combine both the indexOf(): method and the charAt():
>   method – Hussain123

The idea is get next letter based on user input letter.
I'm not sure I wunderstood it, but this is my shot

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phrase = "keyboard";
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

        boolean notContainsInputValue = !phrase.contains(userInput);
        if (notContainsInputValue) {
            System.out.println("The input value doesn't exists");
            return;
        }

        char firstLetter = userInput.charAt(0);
        int desiredIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == firstLetter) {
                desiredIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The index for your input letter is: " + desiredIndex);
        System.out.println("Next letter based on input value is: " + phrase.charAt(desiredIndex + 1));
    }
```

### The Output

```
The index for your input letter is: 5
Next letter based on input value is: r
```

Hope that helps you.